# Can't understand OpenVPN configuration

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I have this client with two offices linked together by an OpenVPN. It wasn't me who configured it and I am having quite a hard time figuring out what the other guy did (I can't contact him, he doesn't answer). Apparently, there are two servers and no client, and both subnets behind each server could see everything on the remote side. The servers are running on 12.04 LTS Ubuntu machines. Server01 is behind a dd-wrt router
bridged to ISP modem. Server02 is connected directly to ISP routed wi-fi modem. There are port forwards correctly configured on both LAN gateways.
IP forwarding is also enabled on both servers. The tunnel is up (I can ping each server from the another).

My problem is: another technician resetted the Server02 modem and everything suddenly stopped working.

Already tried:

- Modifying Openvpn conf files to server-client model;
- Adding static routes to dd-wrt pointing to OpenVPN server;
- Adding static routes to Windows machines on the Server02 LAN;
- Rebooting both servers;
- Rebooting both LAN gateways.

Here are the Openvpn conf files:

Server02

```
    port 1194
    proto udp
    dev tun
    secret static.key
    remote server01.dyndns.org
    # float is needed because server02 is behind stupid ISP router and can't enforce port
    float
    ifconfig 192.168.254.2 192.168.254.1
    #push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
    route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
    comp-lzo
    verb 3
    keepalive 10 60
    fragment 1400
    mssfix
```

Server01

```
    port 1194
    proto udp
    dev tun
    secret static.key
    remote server02.dyndns.org
    float
    ifconfig 192.168.254.1 192.168.254.2
    #push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
    route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
    comp-lzo
    verb 3
    keepalive 10 60
    fragment 1400
    mssfix
```

$iptables -S output on both servers:

```
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks in advance, hope you can help.

Comment: Perhaps resetting the modem changed the global address on the modem. Can you check that your external/global address matches your dynamic DNS name?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Forgot to mention - The tunnel is up (I can ping each server from the another), hence the dynamic dns is working. I just can't see the subnets behind each OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it solved with static routes in Windows and firewall rules in DD-WRT, as follows:

Firewall script on DD-WRT router:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

Static routes on Windows machines behind Server02:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.254.2
```